# Lua 2d rotation gives wierd output for y

Tags: lua, rotation, 2d, trigonometry

I need to be able to perform 2d rotations with lua-script. I think, or at least thought i knew how to do 2d rotations, and for x it works, but for y i get a weird value.

Code:

```
rad = math.rad;
cos = math.cos;
sin = math.sin;

w = 90;

vec = {0, 1};
new_vec = {0, 0};

new_vec[1] = vec[1] * cos(rad(w)) - vec[2] * sin(rad(w));
new_vec[2] = vec[1] * sin(rad(w)) + vec[2] * cos(rad(w));


print("original vector_xy: ", "x= ", vec[1], "y= ", vec[2]);
print("new vector_xy: ", "x= ", new_vec[1], "y= ", new_vec[2]);
```

output:

```
original vector_xy:         x=      0       y=     1
new vector_xy:  x=          -1      y=      6.1232339957368e-017
```

When I test the calculations on a calculator I get the correct answer. Must be something codewise I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the world of floating point.

When you convert 90 degrees to radians, you don't get π/2 exactly, but something quite close to it. The cosine of this angle is not exactly 0, but the very small number you see.

This problem is not specific to Lua.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to get Lua to accept degrees as an argument for cos and sin, that would pretty much solve it :)

Comment: Or perhaps one could round of the value somehow to floor it to 0?

Comment: never mind, I just implemented my own cos and sin functions and let them take degrees, problem solved, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @Mengus, unless you treat special cases explicitly, I don't see how  implementing your own cos and sin functions fixes this.